# R: xlab of multiple variables being cut off in barplot

Tags: r, plot

Hi I have an R barplot

```
barplot(data, xlab = num, cex.names = 0.5)
```

the label is created by

```
num <- c(var1, var2, var3)
```

when the plot is created each variable takes a newline and the last is cut off. Is there a way to make them go on the same line? Thanks

These are the types of values that are in the vector plus how they were obtained in the code.

```
examplefunc<-function(word="category")

rangeStart<-rangeStartValuesVectorized[1]
rangeEnd<-rangeEndValuesVectorized[length(rangeEndValuesVectorized)]
num<-as.character(c(word, rangeStart, rangeEnd))

result<-barplot(Info, main="Mean Plot", xlab=num,cex.names=.5)

rangeEnd=1000
rangeStart=2000
```

Comment: What kind of object is `num`?  If numeric, try `num <- as.character(c(var1, var2, var3))`

Comment: a word and two numbers. The above code doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Show us `num` exactly. A word and two numbers is not possible.  Two different data types cannot co-exist in a single vector, one of them will be coerced.

Comment: alright I posted sample values plus some of the code I used to get the barplot.

Comment: Alas, none of that can be used because we don't have the actual values, and the function doesn't have proper syntax.  But, I can see what you are after in terms of your label, so I'm going to post an answer.

Comment: There are good ideas about writing a reproducible example [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a little paste trick to turn the string of length 3 into a string of length 1 with the same contents:

```
rangeStart <- 5
rangeEnd <- 22
word <- "category"

label <- c(word, as.character(c(rangeStart, rangeEnd)))
label <- paste(label, collapse = " ")

barplot(VADeaths, xlab = label)
```

Comment: Great.  If you hover underneath the downvote arrow you should see a green "accept" check mark which you can click.